# How to write and read Bytes from Port correctly? Getting either null or wrong bytes

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to control a circulator with my serial interface, and after importing Pyserial and opening the port I try to write and read the port's data. First I got wrong data and so I wrote two lines to flush Input and Output. Now either I get null data or this byte: b'?\r\n'.

Maybe I am doing something wrong with the commands. I don't know if I have to handle cr or lf. (carriage return)

An example of the commands:

Command: 'R S1', cr 
Answer: S1+0070.00$

This is my Code. I try to write R S1 on the port and want to read the port afterwards.

```py
while(i <= 3):
    ser.write(b'R S1')
    print(i)
    contents = ser.readline()
    print(contents)
    i = i + 1
```

I expect the result of the current temperature which is 28.5°C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the command you posted, and if the manual of your device is [this one](https://www.labmakelaar.com/fjc_documents/7497_Thermo_Haake_DC50%20Circulator%20&%20Baths_Manual.pdf) I would assume that you're missing the CR (carriage return) character after you send the command.

Try writing this line to the port:

```
ser.write(b'R S1\r')
```

The part where you read should be fine, you're already reading until you get the `<CR><LF>` (carriage return + line feed) characters. But you could also read the exact number of bytes you expect, considering you know them. For this command in particular that would be 13 bytes:

```
contents=ser.read(13)
```

Comment: thanks man, you are my hero =)).

I have got the DC30 but I did not find the character for carriage return.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark as solved to help others. Thank you!